# Environment Variable - Permissions? Quirk? Bug?

Tags: batch-file

I set an environment variable from my batch script:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment" /v TOOL_CHAIN_PATH /t REG_SZ /d C:\Users\MClarkson\Documents\svn\tool-chain /f
```

The batch script runs in elevated permissions mode using the following snippet:

```
rem Make sure we are running in Administrator mode
reg add HKLM\Software\UDP\WindowsInstall\aad3a310a315f101030965e3da3e15b6 /v Elevated /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > nul 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
    echo You must run %~nx0 in elevated mode.  Right-Click and select 'Run as Administrator'
    echo.
    pause
    exit /b 740
)
reg delete HKLM\Software\UDP\WindowsInstall\aad3a310a315f101030965e3da3e15b6 /va /f > nul 2>&1
```

When I open the `cmd.exe` after the script has ran I cannot see the environment variable:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\MClarkson>echo %TOOL_CHAIN_PATH%
%TOOL_CHAIN_PATH%

C:\Users\MClarkson>
```

But if I open up `cmd.exe` as Administrator:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>echo %TOOL_CHAIN_PATH%
C:\Users\MClarkson\Documents\svn\tool-chain

C:\Windows\system32>
```

I can see the environment variable!!

I have noticed that I can run the original `reg add` command as the normal user - it seems there is no restrictions on setting `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and then I can see the environment variable straight away.

Is there someone more experienced with Windows that knows why the normal user cannot see a registry key set by the administrator in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`?

Is there a way to execute a command in an *elevated* batch script at an *unelevated* level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting allows the user to see the environment variable.  Which is annoying, as it's such a simple change.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm I needed a reboot also. This is extremely annoying.